# Current operator from derivative of Hamiltonian with respect to the gauge field

Tags: field-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, second-quantization

For the second-quantized Hamiltonian
$$
H = \int d^3x \psi^\dagger(x)\frac{(-i\nabla - q\vec{A}/c)^2}{2m} \psi(x) + H_{int},\tag{1}
$$
one can conveniently compute the current operator by
$$
j(x) = -c \frac{\delta H}{\delta A(x)},\tag{2}
$$
where $c$ is the speed of light. Is there any physical argument for this formula?

Comment: It is so convenient because we have, when initially choosing how to have the interactions come in, been guided to pick that particular choice. There is thus nothing particularly interesting---it is just one part of the Maxwell's equations that we are writing down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. More generally, an external source/current $J(x)$ couples linearly to its field $\phi(x)$ in the action $S$, so it is natural to expect a formula of the form $J(x)=\delta S/\delta \phi(x)$ for an appropriate action $S$.
2. The Legendre transformation to the Hamiltonian formalism yields a minus sign: $J({\bf x},t)=-\delta H(t)/\delta \phi({\bf x},t)$, which is of the form of OP's eq. (2). The factor of $c$ seems to be conventional.